# Should the Falcon Prism be installed on separate machine than the existing clusters?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, distcp, apache-falcon

I am trying to understand setup for a [Falcon Distributed Cluster](http://falcon.apache.org/0.7/Distributed-mode.html).

I am having Cluster A and Cluster B, both with their Falcon Servers (and namenode, oozie, hive etc.). Now, to install the Prism, what would be the best idea? Shall I install it on one of the clusters (different node than falcon server) or on a different machine? If Prism is set on a third cluster (single node) should it have the components like namenode, oozie etc. running too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism will have a config store where the entities are stored. The configstore will typically be on hdfs and hence needs hadoop client.
So, `yes` the third cluster would need hdfs, namenode etc. Oozie is not necessary.